# Wireless bridge between router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge

I have a modem router (ZTE F660) inside my bedroom (2nd floor), this router has 4 ethernet slots and WiFi. This router is used for TVBOX decoder via ethernet and Internet connection.

So what I'm trying to do is I want to move the TVBOX decoder from my bedroom (2nd floor) to 1st floor (I have another TV on 1st floor) but pulling cable from 2nd floor to 1st isn't an option.

I was thinking of wireless bridge the WiFi signal to 1st floor because I have spare old routers (D'Link DSL-2730u & TP-LINK TD-W8951nd).

- ZTE F660 -> no WDS support
- D'Link DSL -2730u -> no WDS support
- TP-LINK TD-W8951nd -> WDS supported

Is this possible?

[image: task_image]

Comment: While I can't say my solution is in direct response to your question, you could pick up a wireless network switch and try to design your network through there. [Here's an Amazon link to it.](http://www.amazon.com/Amped-Wireless-ProSeries-Gigabit-G8SW/dp/B00PG8WQT4%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduckduckgo-d-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00PG8WQT4) Unfortunately, I am not sure with how these work nor if it is a direct solution to your problem. This isn't a secondary router; it is a network switch.

Comment: (part 2) In order to do this with your existing equipment, you'd likely have to use DD-WRT on your TP-LINK router. However, it doesn't seem like DD-WRT supports said TP-LINK router. I don't think either other routers will help you out in this situation. You might have to go out and buy something similar to the switch I recommended beforehand (read reviews, don't blindly buy that one).

Comment: generally speaking - yes, it's possible, but I assume that the TVBOX is not the only feature you'd like to have available (you'd also like to have internet though wifi for example....) have you checked the option of using one of your old routers as a switch?

Comment: @dsblind: actually connecting the TVBOX is my primary reason because my primary router wifi signal can cover the whole house, the problem with the TVBOX is because it only support ethernet. That being said, any good source on how to use router as switch 101? I googling around but get a mixed answers.

Comment: @warheat1990 If you're going to turn a router into a network switch and connect it to the main router via Ethernet, [here's a great tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/174419/how-to-reuse-your-old-wi-fi-router-as-a-network-switch/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Comment: as I don't know your equipment it's hard for me say..... you should check out manuals at the manufacturer's website and tailor-a-solution for you hardware...... or you can randomly try one of these: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/how-set-up-router-as-repeater-3494655/ , http://lifehacker.com/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-an-old-router-915783308 , http://www.cnet.com/how-to/reuse-an-old-router-to-bridge-devices-to-your-wireless-network/

Comment: @Lildirt: Ohh I already did that, but the problem is I don't want to use ethernet. Hence the wireless bridge in the title because pulling cable from my bedroom to 1st floor isn't an option (too long or I need to drill through wall).

Comment: that's usually what is termed a `repeater`.... but all of those (repeater, switch, node, extender) are used interchangeably, and most recent hardware usually works on the same basic cards and setups - so one of the above should work

Answer (score 0):

As I see it - you need to turn the old machine into an access point or repeater. I assume one of these could help:

1. http://dfarq.homeip.net/2015/06/how-to-use-an-extra-router-as-a-switch/
2. http://www.labnol.org/software/add-router-to-wireless-network/19716/